# Dubbio su quest'ultima frase

Tags: grammar

Con soggetto singolare, dico:

Sono andato a prenderla.

La sono andata a prendere.

Con soggetto plurale:

Sono andati a prenderla.

Poi c'è l'ultima su cui ho dei dubbi:

La sono (loro) andata a prendere o la sono andati a prendere?

A me risultano innaturali entrambe le versioni, ma in realtà a me suona innaturale che  un verbo non transitivo venga usato come transitivo:

La sono andata, le sono andate ecc...

Non ho le basi per poter dire che è agrammaticale, visto che queste forme sono diffuse. 
Ad ogni modo, volendo vederla come se fosse un verbo transitivo, la frase corretta sarebbe  "loro la sono andata a prendere" perché i verbi transitivi concordano col complemento oggetto che in questo caso è femminile singolare.

Comment: La questione è effettivamente complicata, ma attenzione: qui *c'è* un verbo transitivo, che è “prendere”. Col solo verbo andare giustamente non potresti avere un'analoga costruzione (come *“la sono andata”).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il participio nei tempi composti di *andare* va concordato con il soggetto, che in questo caso è *loro* (o *essi*), in generale.

*La sono andata a prendere* è tuttavia ambiguo riguardo al soggetto perché entra in gioco un'altra particolarità dell'italiano: se un pronome precede il participio in un tempo composto, può attirare la concordanza. Supponiamo che un signore si sia recato a prendere la moglie alla stazione:

> la sono andata a prendere

sarebbe corretto. Più probabilmente, il signore direbbe

> sono andato a prenderla

perché la lingua tende a evitare le ambiguità.

*Andare* non può essere transitivo.

Comment: Potresti controllare la prima frase di questo tuo post, @egreg?

Comment: Penso sia una buona risposta, ma forse potrebbe migliorare con un po' più di dettagli.

Comment: @Charo ne sono convinto. Ci lavorerò su più tardi

Comment: Ottimo, @egreg!

Comment: @egreg: quindi "io(uomo) la sono andata a prendere" è sbagliato? La frase è corretta solo se chi va a prendere una determibata cosa è una femmins?

Comment: @egreg: Vedo solo ora questa risposta. Mi suona un po' dubbio che “_La sono andata a prendere_ può essere interpretato solo con soggetto io femminile”. Se Mario racconta di essere andato alla stazione dove era in arrivo sua moglie, non mi suonerebbe strano se dicesse “La sono andata a prendere”. Ma non ci metterei la mano sul fuoco: possiamo approfondire o trovare fonti? Per esempio, cercando al volo, trovo che Alfieri (maschio), parlando di una traduzione scrive “la sono andata limando, e rettificando”.