# Nella grammatica italiana, in quali casi è possibile usare la preposizione "con" in presenza di un verbo riflessivo?

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositions

Ad esempio:

Noi due ci siamo sposati = Noi due abbiamo sposato noi stessi.

Ma si può anche dire:

Mi sono sposato con lei =  Ho sposato me stesso con lei.

Questo tipo di costruzione mi capita di vederla nei casi di forme riflessive reciproche.

Quello che vorrei sapere è se l'uso della preposizione con è idiomatico, quindi non sempre utilizzabile, oppure invece è sempre possibile usarlo con tutte le forme riflessive reciproche.

Grazie mille in anticipo per le risposte.

Comment: A prescindere dalla risposta, il verbo “sposare” è un po' insolito perché si può costruire in vari modi: “A sposa B” (e quindi A e B diventano coniugi), “A si sposa” (ma non significa che A e A formano una coppia), “A sposa B [e C]” (se A è per esempio il sindaco, dopo il cui intervento B e C sono coniugi; da cui le battute quando Ian McKellen sposò – in questo senso – Patrick Stewart). Anticamente “sposare” significava anche “dare, o promettere, in matrimonio”.

Comment: Non capisco molto bene la domanda. Vuoi chiedere se, per esempio, la frase "Romeo e Giulietta si amano" può essere trasformata in "Romeo si ama con Giulietta"? O se invece di "Romeo e Giulietta si sono incontrati" si potrebbe dire "Romeo si è incontrato con Giulietta"?

Comment: @Charo: Romeo e Giulietta si amano = Romeo e Giulietta amano se stessi a vicenda. Romeo e Giulietta si sono incontrati = Romeo e Giulietta incontrano se stessi reciprocamente.   Per quanto riguarda la prima frase, mi pare, non è possibile trasformarla usando la preposizione "con", mentre per la seconda invece sì, eppure sono entrambe frasi con verbi in fuzione riflessiva reciproca. Comunque sì, vorrei sapere in quali casi è possibile usare la preposizione "con" e in quali casi invece no.

Comment: @Nakamura Indagherò ma temo che la risposta sia che dipende da verbo a verbo (quindi bisogna guardare in un buon dizionario per ogni verbo)

Comment: @Nakamura, i riflessivi reciproci si chiamano così perché hanno la forma riflessiva ma indicano un’azione reciproca, non riflessiva; quindi «Noi due ci siamo sposati» non significa «abbiamo sposato noi stessi», ma «io ho sposato te e tu hai sposato me»

Comment: Quando si usa "incontrarsi con qualcuno" o "sposarsi con qualcuno" il verbo non è riflessivo reciproco: si tratta di verbi intransitivi pronominali (vedi, per esempio, l'entrata "[incontrare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/incontrare)" sul Treccani. Alcuni verbi hanno forme diverse dal punto di vista grammaticale e altri no.

Comment: Ad esempio, come puoi vedere sul dizionario, "incontrare" ha una forma transitiva, una forma intransitiva pronominale e una forma riflessiva reciproca. "[Amare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/amare)" ha una forma transitiva e una forma riflessiva che ha quasi sempre valore reciproco. Altri verbi hanno una forma transitiva e un'altra intransitiva, altri hanno unicamente una forma transitiva, ecc. Sono d'accordo con @DenisNardin che per sapere questo l'unico modo è consultare un buon dizionario.

Comment: @Charo: :.https://imgur.com/7455ed99-183f-4eb1-9001-6ff366c1c09 Qui lo da semplicemente come riflessivo. Quindi se ho capito bene, la costruzione con la preposizione "con" non indica mai una forma riflessiva reciproca ma una forma intransitiva pronominale?

Comment: Sì. Tuttavia, il fatto che molti verbi riflessivi reciproci come "sposarsi", "scontrarsi", "incontrarsi", "accapigliarsi", "riconciliarsi"... abbiano una forma intransitiva pronominale con la preposizione "con" con un significato simile alla forma reciproca, ma altri come "amarsi" o "rispettarsi" non l'abbiano mi sembra davvero curioso.

Comment: A proposito, il link che hai messo non sembra funzionare (appare "Oops! We couldn't find that page").

Comment: @Charo: Capisco, quindi: 1) ci siamo conosciuti ieri= forma riflessiva reciproca. 2) mi sono conosciuto con una ragazza= intransitivo pronominale. 3) si sono uniti= riflessivo reciproco. 4) si è unito a/con lei= intransitivo pronominale.

Comment: Sì, è così. Non sapevo che si dicesse "mi sono conosciuto con una ragazza".

Comment: Qui, oltre al problema dei riflessivi (che non sempre significano che l’azione è riflessiva), entra in gioco quello delle preposizioni che in italiano sono davvero tremende :-). Anche nel caso dei verbi, quindi, bisogna guardare caso per caso.

Comment: Provo a documentarmi su «mi sono conosciuto con una ragazza», che non mi sembra corretto.

Comment: È soltanto un'ipotesi, ma sospetto che la cosa abbia a che vedere con quello che @egreg ha scritto in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/10602): "la lingua tende a evitare le ambiguità". Frasi come "mi sono amata/rispettata con Giorgio" potrebbero essere interpretate come "ho amato/rispettato me stessa accanto a Giorgio". Per la stessa ragione non mi suona bene la frase "mi sono conosciuto con una ragazza".